# How to disable ctrl+alt+l shortcut on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: gnome, 18.04, shortcut-keys

I've installed an **Ubuntu 18.04**. When I try to reformatting code shortcut in **PyCharm** - `CTRL+SHIFT+L`, Ubuntu raises something - `Mate-settings-daemon "" is ready` or before:

[image]

I suppose it's because this **Ubuntu** uses this shortcut too but I don't know how to disable it.

I tried to find it in **Keyboard shortcuts**, but it isn't there.

Do you know how to make it work so I can use this shortcut in **PyCharm**?

[image]

Comment: Do you have the mate desktop environment and gnome shell ?

Comment: Not sure, it should be official Ubuntu 18.04...

Comment: did you not install another desktop environment (graphical user interface) than the default one? Mate-settings-daemon is for the Mate desktop and it can't be change in gnome shell

Comment: No I didn't. But I've edited a question and added a new screenshot. This is the window which pop ups when I press ctrl alt l

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and managed to fix it through `dconf editor`. Just did a search for "screensaver", and found the following property with `ctrl + alt + l` as a shortcut: `/org/cinnamon/desktop/keybindings/media-keys/screensaver`. Removed the shortcut, and tried reloading Gnome, without effect. After a reboot it worked though, maybe a relogin would do the trick as well.